# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core application, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Cities.Models.IRepository' while attempting to activate 'Cities.Controllers.HomeController'.

I the `HomeController` I am trying to pass the `Cities` getter to the view like so:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public HomeController(IRepository repo) => repository = repo;

    public IActionResult Index() => View(repository.Cities);
}
```

I have one file `Repository.cs` that contains an interface and its implementation like so:

```cs
public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; }
    void AddCity(City newCity);
}

public class MemoryRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly List<City> cities = new List<City>();

    public IEnumerable<City> Cities => cities;

    public void AddCity(City newCity) => cities.Add(newCity);
}
```

My `Startup` class contains the default-generated code from the template. I have made any changes:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

For the Dependency Injection framework to resolve `IRepository`, it must first be registered with the container. For example, in `ConfigureServices`, add the following:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();
```

For .NET 6+, which uses the [new hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) by default, add the following in *Program.cs* instead:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();
```

`AddScoped` is just one example of a [service lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes):

> For web applications, a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection).

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) for more information on Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 22):

Other answers are CORRECT, however I was spinning up a new asp.net core 2.1.x project and got this error.

Ended up being a typo by ME.

So in my Controller instead of Correctly using the Interface like this

```
public HomeController(IApplicationRepository applicationRepository)
{
    _applicationRepository = applicationRepository;
}
```

My typo had me using `ApplicationRepository` instead of its interface `IApplicationRepository`
Notice below, and so with NO ERRORS spotting the missing "I" was fun :/

```
public HomeController(ApplicationRepository applicationRepository)
{
    _applicationRepository = applicationRepository;
}
```

Thus the controller was not resolving the DI...

Comment: In case anyone else can't find the typo here, the edit to this answer has removed the point you were trying to demonstrate.

Comment: @user120675 Edit is restored.

Answer (score 18):

We are getting this error in Entity frame work core database first approach. I followed below steps and error got resolved

Step 1: Check Your context class constructor should be like this

```
public partial class ZPHSContext : DbContext
{
    public ZPHSContext(DbContextOptions<ZPHSContext> dbContextOptions)
        : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

Step 2: In Startup file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<ZPHSContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

Step 3: Connection string in appsettings

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=****;Database=ZPHSS;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Step 4: Remove default code in OnConfiguring method in context class

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A method like this needs to be added to your `Startup`:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();

    //..
}
```

Services should be registered before used.

**UPDATE:**
If you do not want to use DI on your application, just create and instance of `MemoryRepository` on the constructor of `HomeController`, like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository repository;

        public HomeController()
        {
            repository = new MemoryRepository();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(repository.Cities);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How could my existing code be modified to work without using DI?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your implementation to DI (Dependeny Injection) section. For .Net Core Mvc, it would be like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase()
   );
   services.AddScoped<IRepository, MemoRepostory>();

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be helpful for your code sample but in my case the same error was a result of a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

you have to register your repository like this

`services.AddSingleton<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();`

Comment: using a singleton, I don't think that is a default solution, AddScoped makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

For me I am using visual studio 2022 and .NET 6

the solution was add the following line in the Program.cs file :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHISInterface<UserDetails>, UserDetailsRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to access context  through constructor. like here;

```
 private readonly Context _context;

 public ImageController(Context context)
 {
    _context = context;
 }
```

But When I tried to access  the context  just by creating  an instance of class, it  worked like here;

```
 Context c = new Context();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more possibility that, You might have sent wrong variable in the place while writing this HTTPPOST last part code

mine is

var categoryMap = _mapper.Map(categoryCreate);

```
        if(!_categoryRepository.CreateCategory(categoryMap))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong while saving");
            return StatusCode(500, ModelState);
        }
        return Ok("Successfully created");
```

in the if condition I passed the **category** as parameter instead of **categoryMap**

so please cross check