# How to automatically call a function after pool recycling on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net5

I would like to know-how in my web app written in C#.NET5 (+React) call function after IIS server use setting for recycling Web data on **IIS -> Application Pool -> Recycling (Regular Time Interval (In Minutes)) set on 1440**.

I load over 6 GB to memory (IMemoryCache) and it takes over 6 minutes then all data is loaded, I would like to call the load function to cache automatically after each cycle of the recycling period, before waiting for the user interaction.

I try it call in StartUp, in Main, and also with use IHostetServices, but in each case, I got an error then called service (my class with load method) is not recognized

[3 Ways to Run Code Once at Application Startup in ASP.NET Core](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/3-ways-to-run-code-once-at-application-startup-in-asp-net-core-bcf45a6b6605)

---

I got these errors: when I try to call

```
{"Unable to resolve service for type Repository.DataFilters.Static.IGroupLoader' while attempting to activate 'Search.Startup'."}
```

When I try to call:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");               
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        // Add other security headers
        app.UseMiddleware<SecurityHeadersMiddleware>();

        
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            var isDev = env.EnvironmentName.Contains("Dev");

            if (env.IsDevelopment() || isDev)
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        _GroupLoader.LoadGroupFiltersToMemory(); // try to call this method from my class

    }
```

In ConfiguredService:

```
    private readonly IGroupLoader _GroupLoader;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IGroupLoader groupLoader)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _GroupLoader = groupLoader;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        // DB Contexts
        services.AddDbContext<GroupContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // Services
        services.AddScoped<IGroupService, GroupService>();

        // Repositories
        services.AddScoped<IGroupLoader, GroupLoader>();

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }
```

---

[image]

This solution does not work:

```
<system.webServer>
            <aspNetCore xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(startupTimeLimit)" startupTimeLimit="300">
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
```

After IIS runs Recycling, Its looks like the App is not loaded, I must do an initial run like the open website link, is it possible to load the app automatically after the recycling process of IIS?

In Startup.cs I am not able to call await functions
Called function take over 8 minutes, then all data was loaded

Looks like then I must use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization#TOC301259895

---

**Update 09.01.2022**

After I set IIS and App to autostart I got this error:

[image]

I try to do this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle

In web.config I set:

```
<applicationInitialization
    remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.html" 
    skipManagedModules="true" >
  <add initializationPage="/subpage" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

1. Then when I try to call page **/subpage** (without using Startup.cs ->
   Configure call of IMemoryCache function), the function to load into
   IMemoryCache is not called, but when I run the app with Visual Studio or
   deploy an app to IIS without autostart (warmup), a function is
   called.
2. When I try to call function (with load IMemoryCache) via
   **Startup.cs -> Configure** function, the function is called but IIS server start many (10-11 process) **IIS Worker Process** and I got
   error upper, **also Startup.html webpage is not called during the
   loading process** (I am not sure where must be located in .NET 5
   Core Web App with React Solution).

I got this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

This was maybe caused by many IIS Worker processes which calls the same function (in IMemoryCache loading function I have use `lock()`)

Thank you

Comment: What error you are getting ? Are you warming up application after recycle ?

Comment: I do not a warmup web app (I hear about it the first time that it works with .NET applications), please check my update

Comment: There are similar questions here you can use as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930090/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting-to-activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930090/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting-to-activate).

Comment: I have added a service to DI `services.AddScoped<IGroupLoader, GroupLoader>();` check in my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject your `IGroupLoader` dependency into your `Startup.cs` before the depedency injection has been setup - this is described by the error you provided.

According to this [guide](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/resolve-services-in-aspnet-core-startup), you can inject a dependency in `Configure` once you've setup dependency injection in `ConfigureServices`.

i.e. you need to change:

from

```
 private readonly IGroupLoader _GroupLoader;

 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IGroupLoader groupLoader)
 {
     Configuration = configuration;
     _GroupLoader = groupLoader;
 }
```

to

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

---

from

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

to

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IGroupLoader groupLoader)
```

---

from

```
_GroupLoader.LoadGroupFiltersToMemory();
```

to

```
groupLoader.LoadGroupFiltersToMemory();
```

Comment: After IIS runs Recycling, Its looks like the App is not loaded, I must do an initial run like the open website link(click it or run refresh of website), is it possible to load the app automatically after the recycling process of IIS? Please check my update

Comment: Why do you want to load the app if it's idle? If you want to do something say e.g. every 24 minutes then you could setup [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io) to perform a background task.

Comment: I need to preload data to IMemoryCache before app will be ready

Comment: I update, what I try but without success

Comment: @JanSršeň I'm really not sure at this point, I think you'd need to make `Startup.html` and you might be getting your timeout error because your function takes over 8 minutes to run.

Comment: I have created Startup.html all the time, I would understand that it would give an error during a long load, but I don't know how to extend the time for the first initialization. Now it starts between 10 and 11 processes and then the application crashes, the behavior is weird, I did everything according to the instructions.

Comment: If you want something to load the data for the web app like caching, and that refresh/reload after IIS recycle, then you might want to explore external caching like redis.That way, your app wont rely or impact of IIS app pool recycles.