# ASP.Net Controller to Service connection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

[Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930090/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting-to-activate)

My question was related with this one, but i tried to do what they said to do, and nothing worked.

I am creating a Web API and i am having a error. I want to begin in controller, call the service from controller and call repository from service. But something it is not working and i cannot figure it out. Can someone help me?

[image: Error]

**Controller**

```
namespace uhem_api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TravelPurposeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITravelPurposeService _travelPurposeService;

        public TravelPurposeController(ITravelPurposeService travelPurposeService){
            
           _travelPurposeService = travelPurposeService;
 
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<TravelPurposeDto>> GetAll()
        {
            var res = await _travelPurposeService.GetAll();

            return res;
        }

    }
}
```

**Service**

```
namespace uhem_api.Services
{
    public class TravelPurposeService : ITravelPurposeService
    {
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

**Program.cs**
[image: startup]

Comment: Could you share your code of Program.cs? Do  you register the service ?

Comment: I added the Program.cs file in the question